# Jsp scriplet with HTML tag in it in a loop

Tags: jsp

In my jsp code, all the div tags are inside nested-for loop ('for' writtem in scriptlet). Something like,

```
<% for(i=0;i<5;i++){ %>
    <% for(j=0;j<5;j++){ %>
       <div class="One" id="j">Hey</div>
     <%}%>
 <%}%>
```

The original code is much complex. In this, I want 'Hey' to be displayed 25 times, but it is displaying only 5 times.. once for each iteration of outer loop. How can I solve this and get it displayed i*j times?

Comment: The code you posted will emit 25 divs. Your problem  is elsewhere. Also, consider using [jstl core](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) `foreach` instead of scriptlets.

Comment: This code will emit 25 divs, but with only 5 different ids, which is invalid html, as each id should be unique on the page.  And scriptlets are evil.  You're killing kittens with this code.

Comment: @Don you are right, its a bad practice. If you notice its not even 5 different ids, all ids will be "j".

Comment: Right, my eyes skipped the quotes.  It's one id.

Answer (score 1):

But your code displaying hey 25 times ....... I think no problem with your code... Here is my screen shot..

[image]